# MadCow Routine - When to stop / restart?

Tags: weightlifting, exercise, strength, muscle, workout

In this pic I added the first day of my MadCow spreadsheet.

My question(s) are:

When do I stop (start over)?
For example, if I started `Week 6` and I will try to `squat` `5 reps` of `110kg`
But I only manage to do `4 reps`

Do I then update my `Squat` and start again on `week 1`?
Or should I keep going until I am unable to do even `1 rep`?

---

Second.

If I fail at doing `5 reps` in `squat`, but I manage to do `5 reps` in `benchpress`, **IF** I have to restart my `squat` then, do I also have to restart my `benchpress`, or can they be on seperate weeks?

Example

Squat is reset and is now on week 2
Benchpress is still going and is on week 8

[image: MadCow First Day]

Answer (score 4):

You don't "start over" unless you stop lifting for several months. The point is to *always be stronger for the rest of your life*. The point is not to lift the weight and then pretend you can't lift the heavy weight.

If you miss a rep on one exercise, it doesn't affect the others. They track separately.

If you miss one rep of, say, a squat, then try that weight again the next workout. If you miss again, then back off by 10% in the next workout (or "rewind" a week), then continue progressing. Never go back to Week 1 unless you quit entirely and are restarting the program months later after you're weak again.